# Will new return the named function constructor instance-?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

```
var foo = function () {
    return new moo();
}

var moo = function () {
    return this;
}
```

If I execute the statement

```
new foo()
```

will I actually get an instance of moo?  This seems at both the same time obvious and non-intuitive.  Functionally, this is what should happen, but at the same time this is not-expected if you didn't know the internals.

EDIT: I realized this seems unintuitive b.c. in Java constructors can not return anything.

This is very similar to the constructor pattern that jquery uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will get an instance of moo.

non-intuitiveness is because of the fact that you can return something other than object itself in a javascvipt constructor.This is possible because all functions are in fact objects in js.  In languages like java and c# that's not possible, constructor always returns object which constructor belongs to. You can also cannot call contructors without new keyword in such languages. 
Not returning anything from constructor is same thins as `return this;` in js thing(assuming it's used a constructor) also adds a little to confusion.

Comment: its because this keyword is not used!!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct you will get an instance of moo

The reason for this being so ambiguous is because whenever new keyword is used, **`the newly created object's constructor is not executed until 'this' keyword is used`**. the new object is bound to 'this' keyword.

refer this from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

> When the code new foo(...) is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from foo.prototype.
> 2. The constructor function foo is called with the specified arguments and this bound to the newly created object. new foo is
>      equivalent to new foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, foo is
>      called without arguments.
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't
>      explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
>      instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can
>      choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
>      process.)

In your example, too a new Object is created but 'this' keyword is not used and hence the constructor for foo is not called and hence the function just ends up returning the moo object.

http://jsfiddle.net/v5aGu/

```
var foo = function () {
    return new moo();
}

var moo = function () {
    return this;
}

var myFoo = new foo(2);
if(myFoo instanceof moo){
    alert("moo");
}
if(myFoo instanceof foo){
    alert("foo");
}
```

Edit: to Answer question raised by @Desu

```
id = 0;

var foo = function(){

}

if(new foo() instanceof foo){
 alert("yes"); //alerts yes
}
```

**JavaScript Constructors 101 :**

1. The default behavior of constructor is to return 'this' if nothing else is returned
2. If another object is returned from a constructor the newly created object bound to 'this' gets discarded

http://jsfiddle.net/xQVuX/1/

```
id = 0;

var foo = function(){
}

if(new foo() instanceof foo){
 alert("foo yes"); //alerts foo yes because foo returns this as a default behavior
}

var foo2 = function(){
    var i=new foo();
    return i;
}

if(new foo2() instanceof foo2){
 alert("foo2 yes");// does not alert because foo2 returns another object and the newly created object is discarded
}

var foo3 = function(){
    this.i = 10; 
}

if(new foo3() instanceof foo3){
    alert("foo3 yes"); // alerts foo3 yes because foo3 returns this as a default behavior
}
```

Comment: @stack_temp does `this` answer your question?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xQVuX/) `the newly created object's constructor is not executed until 'this' keyword is used` is not true. the function itself is the constructor, if it's not executed new moo would not be executed either.